# ASP.NET Routing Url

Tags: asp.net, web, webforms

I have registered the following route

```
routes.MapPageRoute("RouteMyPage", "MyPage/{myParameter}", "~/MyPage.aspx");
```

It works fine when I call it with parameter

```
Response.Redirect(GetRouteUrl("RouteMyPage", new { myParameter = "ValueParameter" }));
```

But when I call it with the parameter `MyParameter` set to null, I get an error

```
Response.Redirect(GetRouteUrl("RouteMyPage", null));
```

> **System.ArgumentNullException**: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: url

Could someone help me how to solve this problem or in short, it is not possible to pass the parameter as null?

Thank you

Comment: ***WHAT*** error ?!?!? Remember - we can neither see your screen, nor read your mind - you need to **SHOW US!**

Comment: jajaja, sorry. The exception is:  Exception Message: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: url

Exception Type: System.ArgumentNullException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply do:

```
string myParameter = "ValueParameter";
Response.Redirect($"/MyPage/{myParameter}");
```